# IP tables modification to allow access to mysql on CENTOS 5 server

Tags: mysql, centos, iptables

CentOS 5.4, with IP tables stopped, I can do it. What's the line I need to add to IPtables so I can keep it on and have remote (domain) access to the mysql databases?

my current table:

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-securitylevel
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p 50 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p 51 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp --dport 5353 -d 224.0.0.251 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 10.0.1.1/24 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 10.0.1.1/24 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 10.0.1.1/24 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 10.0.1.1/24 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 10.0.1.1/24 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just using "-A" adds the rule to the end of the chain, and as mark suggested, this will put the mysql ACCEPT after the blanket REJECT; no packet will ever get to it.

You can either edit the /etc/sysconfig/iptables file to add the line

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

immediately **after** the line

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

and then restart the iptables service, or you could manually do it with

```
iptables -I RH-Firewall-1-INPUT 11 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

which will put it in the same place, but need to be done after each reboot.

Comment: You rock! It worked. I was a bit nervous when you said "but need to be done after each reboot," but I guessed you meant restart. Anyway, it worked after manual edit and service iptables restart. Thanks.

Comment: To avoid having to add the rule after each reboot do `sudo service iptables save`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: for a specific address ip address: iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -s IP_ADDRESS -j ACCEPT

Comment: @bindbn: it didn't work. I added my iptables to my original post if it helps. Hmmm, when I enter your command at the prompt and then look at the table, it does not appear to be adding/changing anything???

Comment: The file you have included is /etc/sysconfig/iptables, which configures the firewall at boot (strictly, at iptables service start) time.  It does not change as you add or delete rules from the running firewall.  "iptables -L -n -v" will tell you the state of the current, running firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your firewall is set up currently, you will optionally need the outgoing one and you also may need to fiddle with the order of the rules so that these come before any blanket REJECT or DROP rules you might already have.

```
# for incoming
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
# for outgoing
iptables -A OUTPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 3306 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I edited my original post after seeing your answer. Does that change your response?